# python print equivalent in vbscript using visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, vbscript

I have some experience with python, Now I'm trying to write my first script in VB using visual studio.

in python to view a result of something I can just print it.

```
a=1
b=2
c=a+b
print c
3
```

in visual studio I have the command window, how can I do the same in VBscript?

```
dim a=1
dim b=2
dim c
c= a+b
print c
```

that didn't work
would appreciate some help with this
complete novice with visual studio and vbscript

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cf7t4xt(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

i think it is Echo and  for [reference](http://ss64.com/vb/echo.html)

```
WScript.Echo("Hello")
```

Comment: Please remove the parentheses from the `"Hello"`. In the given context they have a [different meaning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) than what people expect.